# Why doesn't sort give me the right values if there isn't a line after it?

Tags: c++, sorting

When sort doesn't have a line following it, the results are incorrect. I put a breakpoint on the sort line, and stepped over until the sort line had run, and inspected the values of `myvector`.
[image]

But when there is a line following it, even though the line has nothing to do with the myvector variable, I get the right values. Here I could put the breakpoint after the sort, so I needed need to step over anything. What's going on here?
[image]

Comment: This looks like an issue with how you're using the IDE rather than a C++ issue. Can you talk us through the exact steps you're using to get the screenshots here?

Comment: @templatetypedef added some details on what I did for each screenshot.

Comment: In the first picture `myvector` is already out of scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a foible with the IDE & debugger.

If you're stepping "onto" that closing brace, you're observing the values of things after they've been destroyed, i.e. nothing.

When you step onto an actual statement that exists in the code, everything is still alive so your debugger works properly.

Ideally your IDE wouldn't allow this, or at least would be clear about it. I do vaguely recall seeing this issue here before.

In reality, you'd always be "doing something" with this vector (e.g. returning it; otherwise why create and sort it?) so you'll always have a meaningful statement to break on after your `sort` call.

Comment: Ahh I understand, that makes a lot of sense! Thanks